# FlashRadioButon

Tags: flash

var opt1_MC = ansr.createClassObject(mx.controls.RadioButton, "choice_Mc", ansr.getNextHighestDepth(), {label"test",data:"test",groupName:"questionChoiceGroup"});
opt1_MC.setStyle("fontWeight", "bold");

here font weight i had changed as italic , but it not set .. flash cs2 --? why.. 
any one can help me ?.thanks

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer

opt1_MC.setStyle("fontStyle", "italic");